# "You have ad crawler errors" but website works perfectly on any device/proxy

Tags: mysql, wordpress, adsense, robots.txt, google-search-console

I have a WordPress website, and in AdSense, I get this error:

[image]
That is the income I get from that site; it usually goes to 10 Euro/Day

This is mydomain.com/robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-content/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /archives/
Disallow: /comments/feed/
Disallow: /trackback/
Disallow: /index.php
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
Disallow: *?wptheme
Disallow: ?comments=*
Disallow: /search?
Disallow: /?p=*
Disallow: /feeds

User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*
Allow: /
```

Also Webmaster Tools verification methods DOES NOT WORK.

I tried all ways except txt record.
mydomain.com/googlexxxxx.html shows google-site-verification: googlexxxxx.html but google cannot see it.

Searching for site://mydomain.com shows results.

Google Analytics work

Website traffic is the same

I Reinstalled the whole site, added a new WordPress script, theme, and plugins but used previous DB.

Other sites on my VPS work smooth, AdSense shows perfectly.

Could my server blocked AdSense ip?

The issue appeared when I started to get notifications about updating MySQL.

For a reason, I cannot contact Google.
What do you think I should Try/Do further?

Comment: *For a reason I cannot contact Google.* That would have been my advise